# Concatenating the cell value in one data frame with the corresponding cell value in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames containing aggregated data. The first data frame consists of the median values of 3 groups (Group 1, Group 2, and Group 3) that have undergone scenario A, B, and C.

My second data frame consists of the sample size of 3 groups (Group 1, Group 2, and Group 3) that have undergone scenario A, B, and C.

The data looks something like the following:

```
median_data <- data.frame(Group = c(1, 2, 3), scenario_A = c(296.7, 152.3, 113.6), 
                      scenario_B = c(109, 76, 79), scenario_C = c(321.5, 236.5, 191))

sample_size_data <- data.frame(Group = c(1, 2, 3), scenario_A = c(113, 121, 59),
                           scenario_B = c(100, 100, 55), scenario_C = c(100, 100, 55))
```

I want to convert the values in the Scenario columns in both data frames into character data type and concatenate the value in one cell of the first data frame (Median) with the corresponding cell in the second data frame (Sample size).

I have searched on Stackoverflow; this is not a rbind/cbind question. The desired output I have in mind is to concatenate Row 1 Column 1 from data frame 1 with Row 1 Column 1 from data frame 2, and so forth.

The desired output looks like the following:
[image: Desired Output]

I have tried the following code, and it is almost correct. I am not sure how to change it to a 3 rows, 4 columns data frame and that the sample size for column 1 (Group) in the resultant data frame should not be there.

```
df <- data.frame(paste(apply(median_data, 2, as.character), " (n = ", 
                   apply(sample_size_data, 2, 
                         as.character), ")",sep = ""))
```

Thanks and much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `paste` the corresponding columns of both `data.frame`s with `Map`

```
out <- median_data
out[-1] <- Map(function(x, y) sprintf("%0.1f (n = %d)", x, y),  
            median_data[-1], sample_size_data[-1])
```

---

Or convert the `data.frame` to `matrix` and `paste`

```
out  <- median_data
out[-1] <-  paste0(as.matrix(median_data[-1]), " (n=", 
              as.matrix(sample_size_data[-1]), ")") 

out
#   Group    scenario_A  scenario_B    scenario_C
#1     1 296.7 (n=113) 109 (n=100) 321.5 (n=100)
#2     2 152.3 (n=121)  76 (n=100) 236.5 (n=100)
#3     3  113.6 (n=59)   79 (n=55)    191 (n=55)
```

Comment: The sample size in each column is wrong. Following concatenation, the values in the Group column in the Sample Size data frame should not be in the resultant data frame.

Comment: @DTYK OOps, I forgot `[-1]`.  >Corrected the output

Comment: I am trying to understand your 2nd solution. Why did you have to convert the two data frames to matrices? Isn't it possible to arrive at the solution using data frames following the same logic? Thanks!

Comment: @DTYK `paste` works with vectors, and a matrix is a `vector` with dimensions and that is the reason I converted

Comment: I see. Thanks. Why don't paste work with data frames? If I recall correctly, each column in a data frame is a vector, so why does it not work on vectors from a data frame? Thanks again!

Comment: @DTYK  You are right that columns are vectors and it works on each column and that is the reason we loop using `Map` or with `lapply`

Answer (score 4):

Pass a counter to the apply statement to index the second dataframe

```
i<-1

x<-as.data.frame(apply(median_data[,-1], 2, function(x) {
  i<<-i+1
  paste0(x, " (n = ",sample_size_data[,i],")")
}))

x<-cbind(Group=median_data[,1], x)

x
  Group      scenario_A    scenario_B      scenario_C
1     1 296.7 (n = 113) 109 (n = 100) 321.5 (n = 100)
2     2 152.3 (n = 121)  76 (n = 100) 236.5 (n = 100)
3     3  113.6 (n = 59)   79 (n = 55)    191 (n = 55)
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr). We can prepare both data frames as character, use `bind_rows` to combine them, and then use `group_by` and `summarise_all` to concatenate all columns.

```
library(dplyr)

median_data2 <- median_data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Group), funs(as.character(.)))

sample_size_data2 <- sample_size_data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Group), funs(paste0("(n = ", ., ")")))

dat <- bind_rows(median_data2, sample_size_data2) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(paste(., collapse = " "))) %>%
  ungroup()
dat
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   Group scenario_A      scenario_B    scenario_C     
#   <dbl> <chr>           <chr>         <chr>          
# 1     1 296.7 (n = 113) 109 (n = 100) 321.5 (n = 100)
# 2     2 152.3 (n = 121) 76 (n = 100)  236.5 (n = 100)
# 3     3 113.6 (n = 59)  79 (n = 55)   191 (n = 55)
```